# If a certain operation/operator appears in actual query plan then is it necessary that the operation has executed?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-profiler, sql-execution-plan

I have captured **Showplan XML Statistics Profile** event class and I got this plan . I have also captured  **Scan:Started** event class.

Here is a part of the plan that appears for **Showplan XML Statistics Profile**

[image]

What took me by surprise is that although my query doesn't scan EmailComments table and do full text search they are appearing in the plan( in the red box) .

My understanding was only those operation that are actually performed should be in the plan. 
I am new to profiling and query optimization.
Can somebody guide me what am i missing?

Comment: Select the operator and have a look at "number of executions " in the properties window. It can be zero. If none zero please upload the XML for the actual execution plan somewhere. And showing us the query and relevant object definitions would also help.

Comment: Thanks Martin!!! u saved my night :) . Now i can join the pieces.